# P.communicate() returns no output but exit code is 0

Tags: python

I am getting no output from the following code but it is not producing an error either.  When command is typed manually on command line I get a lot of output.

```
grepCommand = "box | grep " + grepHostKey
grepCommand = grepCommand.split()

p = subprocess.Popen(grepCommand, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(hostString, err) = p.communicate()
print hostString    
print err
```

output:

If I add shell=True I get the expected response from just the "box" command and it is not piped into the grep.  I have seen it is advised to not use shell=True.  I have tried bufsize=8192 which is big enough to handle but still nothing.  Any thoughts as to what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The pipe is a shell symbol. That is why this could only work with shell=True. But as you have said, this is not best practice. Here is a code you can use to manually pipe commands with subprocess.

```
box_process = Popen(["box"], stdout=PIPE)
grep_process = Popen(["grep", grepHostKey], stdin=box_process.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
box_process.stdout.close()
(hostString, err) = grep_process.communicate()
```

Comment: upvote for _not_ recommending `shell=True` :)